# Detecting version of SqlSysClrTypes for 2014 vs. 2014 SP1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have code written for my installers that detects the versions of various SQL add-ons (SysClrTypes, SMO, etc.) so that I can determine if/when my installer should install/upgrade the version of those products.

Until now, I have always been able to find a way to differentiate between all the different versions and service packs.  However, today, I cannot seem to find a way to differentiate between SysClrTypes for SQL 2014 and 2014sp1.

The method I have been using to detect the version of SysClrTypes is to locate the file, "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll", look at the version information, and grab the 'ProductVersion' property.  For SQL 2014, that version number is 12.0.2000.8.

While preparing to support 2014 SP1, I installed SysClrTypes for 2014 on a test system, confirmed the version number was 12.0.2000.8, and then installed SysClrTypes for 2014 sp1.  BUT NOTHING CHANGED!  The installer knew that I had an older version installed, because it asked if I wanted to update.  If I try to install the old version again, the installer detects that too, and says I can't install an older version.  But I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how the installer knew that.

There must be some way to detect it.  Anybody know what methodology can be used to differentiate between SysClrTpes for 2014 and for 2014sp1?

Dennis

Comment: The installer is looking at the registry keys for the GUIDs of the MSI installer package. It's not looking at the dlls.

Comment: I discovered that too, dman2306.  I installed 4 different versions: 2014(x86), 2014SP1(x86), 2014(x64) and 2014SP1(x64).  Indeed, the uninstaller registry entries are apparently the only difference, which begs the question, why distribute a SP1 version if there is no difference in the distro files?

MS did not distribute 2014 versions of SqlCmdLnUtils, because there were no changes from the 2012 SP2 versions.  So why distribute a 2014SP1 for ClrTypes that is, AFAICT, identical to the 2014 version?  Strange.

Comment: For anyone else looking for the same info, here's what I found:  
2014 (x86): HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{718FFB65-F6E4-4D62-861F-ED10ED32C936}  
2014 SP1 (x86): HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{71BBE068-233F-403C-88B8-C2FDE753F6B0}  
2014 (x64): HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{68BA34E8-9B9D-4A74-83F0-7D366B532D75}  
2014 SP1 (x64):HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{E3F613C1-105F-4717-BFE7-007729A95D67}  
In each case, there is a DisplayVersion value.